# Where is the 'Autos' view in msdev 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, debugging, visual-studio-2003

When debugging in msdev 2003, there is a very convenient 'Autos' window that show vars and values around currently-executed line.

I cannot find anything similar in msdev 2005. Is it dead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to Visual Studio 2005, it can be found at Debug -> Windows -> Autos on the main menu.

This can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> or, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> if you use the C# keybindings (which is easier to press).

Additionally, the Autos tool window is only visible when debugging.

Comment: It's in the same place in VS2008 as well.

Comment: @bevan -- yup, I was simply clarifying that "msdev 2005" = "Visual Studio 2005" in the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Debug -> Windows -> Autos

It may be showing just part of some other widget-group.  Look around for a little tab that says "Autos" on it.  Typically it lurks with Watch 1 and Locals.

Also you can press CTRL+ALT+V, A.

Answer (score 0):

VS has the tendency to lose windows and sometime to reset menu mappings to have minimal amount of actually useful commands. Whenever that happens, you can dig them back via Tools|Customize -> Commands. Look in different categories, for example Autos is in Debug. From here you can drag the command onto menu or toolbar.

In the Customize window there is also good-to-have-on checkbox "Show shortcuts".